# ES6 Array push and merge if value already exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am creating a shopping cart based on recipes.

```
this.shoppingCartRecipes.forEach(recipe => {
      recipe.ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
        this.shoppingCart.push({
          amount: ingredient.amount,
          unit: ingredient.unit,
          name: ingredient.ingredient,
          isDone: ingredient.isDone || false,
          recipeID: recipe.id
        });
      });
    });
```

But I would like to merge values, if ingredient name and ingredient unit are the same. Is there a smart way to do that?

Comment: why to use loop to push in the same object?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar, most probably `this.ingradients` refers to a property outside of the loop.

Comment: I would personally use an object, if you need to keep track of the same value. Otherwise, you may want to use `.find` to check whether an ingredient already exists; if it does, you alter that object specifically.

Comment: @JordanEnev ah, yeah. din't notice that.

Comment: What do you mean with merge values? Which values you want to merge? I don't quite understand what's the issue

Comment: Can you give a basic sample of input (including a merge step) and the expected output, so we can understand what you expect to get as result of the merging logic?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep `this.shoppingCart` as array:

```
this.shoppingCartRecipes.forEach(recipe => {
  recipe.ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
    const shoppingCartIngredient = this.shoppingCart.find( item => (
      (item.name === ingredient.ingredient) && (item.unit === ingredient.unit)
    ))

    // If the ingredient exists, just update it
    if (shoppingCartIngredient) {
      shoppingCartIngredient.amount = ingredient.amount;
      shoppingCartIngredient.isDone = ingredient.isDone || false;
      shoppingCartIngredient.recipeID = recipe.id;
    } else {
      // Otherwise create a new record
      this.shoppingCart.push({
        amount: ingredient.amount,
        unit: ingredient.unit,
        name: ingredient.ingredient,
        isDone: ingredient.isDone || false,
        recipeID: recipe.id
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lodash' library :

use `_.uniq(array);` or `_.uniqBy(array);` after push .

Comment: I would prefer a solution without lodash. It adds quite of "weight" to the project.